# Using MongoDB should I nest everything related to a user in the user schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Threw an example below, makes the question easier I think. Should I do this, or is it better for performance to split things up? I'm probably going to want to add things to this later too, down the line.

```
user: new schema({
    key: type.unique.string // uuid
  , nickname: type.string
  , username: type.unique.string
  , password: type.string
  , email: type.optional.string
  , role: { type: String, required: true, default: 'user', enum: ['user', 'administrator'] }
  , active: type.bool
  , created: type.timestamp
  , last: type.timestamp
  , products: { type: [{ product: type.string, cost: type.number, when: type.timestamp, where: type.string }] }
  , sessions: { type: [{ who: type.unique.string, when: type.timestamp, where: type.number, what: type.string }] }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no right answer to this. It will depend on a lot of factors that only you know.

Some documentation to help you decide:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/